# Getting HTML of a Cake PHP form

Tags: forms, cakephp, form-helpers

I am creating a form  using Cake PHP. Is there any way to retrieve the basic HTML of the created form. For example,if we use Form Helper, we can create form using PHP itself. But now, I need only the html part of the created form for other use. Is it possible to retrieve it??

For example, say if I give input form like,

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create('User');
  echo $this->Form->input('email');
  echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

I need output like this

```
<form action="index.html">
<input type="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I can even create seperate function for attaining this objective. But I would like to know, if there is any other method for achieving this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store FormHelper output in a string variable

```
<?php
  $html_string = '';
  $html_string .= $this->Form->create('User');
  $html_string .= $this->Form->input('email');
  $html_string .= $this->Form->end('Save');


?>
```

and then use your string elsewhere. But I'm not sure this is what you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks.. This is what I expected.I've now got idea on seeing your answer. Storing form in variable works for my task.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use the form you created on another part of your site?

If that is the case, I would put the form itself in an Element and then call the Element wherever I wanted the form.

```
View/Elements/form.ctp
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create('User');
  echo $this->Form->input('email');
  echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

Then in any view on your site you can call the Element using:

```
<?php echo $this->element('form');?>
```

Comment: You've understood my question correctly. But I do not want to go with storing each forms in elements. I need to generate the form html. That's it. I will copy that and use it in other place. Is there any way for converting the php created form to its purest form of HTML

Comment: I don’t understand. You want to generate the form HTML, use that HTML in multiple places, but you *don’t* want to use an element? What *do* you want to do?

Comment: @MartinBean Good question.. I am having form creating cake php script. Need to convert that to html..

Comment: @Ganesh But the form helper *returns* HTML. What do you want?

Comment: @MartinBean Form helper returns HTML in browser.. I want that HTML output in a seperate place..

Comment: @Ganesh Can you give an example as to why you would generate HTML one place and use it in another? It sounds like you’re going against CakePHP’s conventions otherwise.